# How to code for independent 2 sample t-test (x,y)

Tags: r

I need to write an algorithm for x and y and carry out a two sample *t*-test (not using build in function)

```
x = c(2,4,6,8,9,10,12,14)
y = c(3,5,7,9,12,13,15,18)
```

Two-sample *t*-test applicable to the two samples x and y. The arguments to this function should include: x, y, the hypothesized mean difference delta0,
and an option indicating left-tailed, right-tailed or two-tailed test.

How would I do this using R?
I need a code, not just the build in feature.

I have done this so far, but I need my `t_test` function to return sample sizes and sample means for both samples, its degree of freedom, and the p-value

```
x = c(2,4,6,8,9,10,12,14)
y = c(3,5,7,9,12,13,15,18)
nx = length(x)
ny = length(y)
sp = sqrt(((nx-1)*var(x)+(ny-1)*var(y))/(nx+ny-2))
s1 = sp*sqrt(1/nx+1/ny)
mu0 = 0
t = (sample.mean(x)-sample.mean(y)-mu0) / s1
t
```

Here is the 2 datasets. The file “expr_data" contains microarray gene expression data for 17 breast cancer patients, each with an ID string starting with “GSM”. Each row in that data file represents a gene(probeset). These 17 patients belong to three different treatment groups: Control, Treatment1 and Treatment2, with their group memberships specified in a "group_data"

**Dataset 1**

```
> head(expr_data)
          GSM119944 GSM119945 GSM119946 GSM119947 GSM119948 GSM119949
1007_s_at 11.376519 11.826743 11.123022 11.743439 12.172961 11.522009
1053_at    7.270398  7.534450  7.169297  7.730833  6.728914  7.033900
117_at     8.172823  8.350568  8.216073  8.052177  7.940714  8.122496
121_at    10.064195 11.193688  9.846189 10.549992 10.172722 10.357284
1255_g_at  6.256425  6.830607  5.825010  6.098157  6.104971  5.818458
1294_at    9.347887  9.540260  9.229501  9.464348  9.764903  9.962180
          GSM119950 GSM119951 GSM119952 GSM119953 GSM119954 GSM119955
1007_s_at 11.288407 11.364544 11.783231 12.102697 12.141934 12.141672
1053_at    8.152550  7.357942  7.811469  6.704366  7.723678  7.607720
117_at     8.246269  7.597745  8.809971  7.299070  7.808597  8.390707
121_at    11.361081 10.446139 11.165541 10.285435 10.123556 10.532735
1255_g_at  6.355995  6.311312  7.366574  5.577412  4.570794  5.046956
1294_at    9.300450  9.230649  9.783263  8.749285  9.466965  9.653450
          GSM119956 GSM119957 GSM119958 GSM119959 GSM119960 GeneSymbol
1007_s_at 11.541161 12.069206 11.529456  9.692066 11.242988       DDR1
1053_at    6.904579  6.837490  7.437899  7.608960  6.704648       RFC2
117_at     7.653514  8.680945  8.050873  9.242006  8.253535      HSPA6
121_at    10.379335 10.487541 10.542419 10.248043 10.207259       PAX8
1255_g_at  6.561945  5.897955  5.402725  5.957542  6.201037     GUCA1A
1294_at    9.076623  9.827835  9.096732  9.441370  9.102000       UBA7
          PublicID
1007_s_at   U48705
1053_at     M87338
117_at      X51757
121_at      X69699
1255_g_at   L36861
1294_at     L13852
```

**Dataset 2**

```
> groups_data
   PatientID TreatmentGroup
1  GSM119946        Control
2  GSM119948        Control
3  GSM119951        Control
4  GSM119955        Control
5  GSM119956        Control
6  GSM119959        Control
7  GSM119947     Treatment1
8  GSM119950     Treatment1
9  GSM119952     Treatment1
10 GSM119953     Treatment1
11 GSM119957     Treatment1
12 GSM119958     Treatment1
13 GSM119944     Treatment2
14 GSM119945     Treatment2
15 GSM119949     Treatment2
16 GSM119954     Treatment2
17 GSM119960     Treatment2
```

Using the Two-sample t test function that I am writing I need to test all the genes individually (comparing the control patient group and treatment 1 patient group) with a null hypothesis that mu_control=mu_treat1 and an alternative hypothesis that mu_control < mu_treat1.

Here is the two datasets merged if that helps

head(groups_expr)
  GSM119944 GSM119945 GSM119946 GSM119947 GSM119948 GSM119949 GSM119950
1 11.376519 11.826743 11.123022 11.743439 12.172961 11.522009 11.288407
2  7.270398  7.534450  7.169297  7.730833  6.728914  7.033900  8.152550
3  8.172823  8.350568  8.216073  8.052177  7.940714  8.122496  8.246269
4 10.064195 11.193688  9.846189 10.549992 10.172722 10.357284 11.361081
5  6.256425  6.830607  5.825010  6.098157  6.104971  5.818458  6.355995
6  9.347887  9.540260  9.229501  9.464348  9.764903  9.962180  9.300450
  GSM119951 GSM119952 GSM119953 GSM119954 GSM119955 GSM119956 GSM119957
1 11.364544 11.783231 12.102697 12.141934 12.141672 11.541161 12.069206
2  7.357942  7.811469  6.704366  7.723678  7.607720  6.904579  6.837490
3  7.597745  8.809971  7.299070  7.808597  8.390707  7.653514  8.680945
4 10.446139 11.165541 10.285435 10.123556 10.532735 10.379335 10.487541
5  6.311312  7.366574  5.577412  4.570794  5.046956  6.561945  5.897955
6  9.230649  9.783263  8.749285  9.466965  9.653450  9.076623  9.827835
  GSM119958 GSM119959 GSM119960 GeneSymbol PublicID PatientID TreatmentGroup
1 11.529456  9.692066 11.242988       DDR1   U48705 GSM119946        Control
2  7.437899  7.608960  6.704648       RFC2   M87338 GSM119946        Control
3  8.050873  9.242006  8.253535      HSPA6   X51757 GSM119946        Control
4 10.542419 10.248043 10.207259       PAX8   X69699 GSM119946        Control
5  5.402725  5.957542  6.201037     GUCA1A   L36861 GSM119946        Control
6  9.096732  9.441370  9.102000       UBA7   L13852 GSM119946        Control

tail(groups_expr)
       GSM119944 GSM119945 GSM119946 GSM119947 GSM119948 GSM119949 GSM119950
378806  4.671951  4.731546  3.364612  2.893266  2.450373 4.6563807  4.375824
378807  2.954090  4.653969  2.695438  3.193373  3.685037 3.9202165  5.387476
378808  3.159816  5.216588  3.989162  5.387770  5.579206 5.9640708  4.796789
378809  1.464918  1.892150  1.398225  1.780359  1.477039 0.8966322  5.217179
378810  3.567588  3.642495  5.003216  3.565525  4.190032 3.2998454  4.903368
378811  2.959766  3.164650  1.462571  2.681616  2.646549 3.3482051  3.317340
       GSM119951 GSM119952 GSM119953 GSM119954 GSM119955 GSM119956 GSM119957
378806  3.501316  5.121043  2.957501  3.072479  3.395843  3.183937  3.332907
378807  4.008853  3.808073  3.356645  3.979238  3.327875  3.143567  3.500472
378808  2.468878  4.937979  3.568130  3.105428  5.978494  3.431517  5.485591
378809  4.893662  2.465712  1.967586  1.632630  1.051223  2.272937  1.399148
378810  5.079019  3.653048  2.997752  4.118145  4.460848  5.101762  3.812710
378811  1.259031  2.661944  2.537223  2.692363  2.333142  1.011025  2.732608
       GSM119958 GSM119959 GSM119960 GeneSymbol     PublicID PatientID
378806  4.230085  3.740862  2.963901             AFFX-ThrX-3 GSM119960
378807  3.405755  3.703066  3.421292             AFFX-ThrX-5 GSM119960
378808  4.333555  5.543589  3.771600             AFFX-ThrX-M GSM119960
378809  4.217012  2.025573  2.080592            AFFX-TrpnX-3 GSM119960
378810  5.254337  3.054821  4.731657            AFFX-TrpnX-5 GSM119960
378811  2.621702  1.619972  2.243780            AFFX-TrpnX-M GSM119960
       TreatmentGroup
378806     Treatment2
378807     Treatment2
378808     Treatment2
378809     Treatment2
378810     Treatment2
378811     Treatment2

There is 378811 rows, I need to t-test all these rows (genes) to compare Treatment1 and Control patients (GSM****** is the patient Id).

Comment: This sounds like a homework assignment and that's not what Stack Overflow is for. If you don't know the proper formulas to use, then that's a question about statistics and not programming which would be off-topic for this site.

Comment: Hi MrFlick, it is a gene expression project, and I just need to create my own ttest function, I understand the statistics, just have no clue how to code, it, I would really value your advice to help me. I am a biomedical scientist and have branched into bioinformatics and really dont understand the computer code area.

Comment: So if you understand the statistics, what's the specific programming question you have? What value do you know how to calculate on paper but don't know how to calculate in R? Right now you just asking someone to build a complicated function for you, when then whole point of using R is that such a function is built in.

Comment: Like a lot of people here, who are not from computer area, but learned by themselves. Currently, your question is off-topic. Please share some sample code, to show your efforts.

Comment: shared some their now :) needs edited though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [here](http://www.statsdirect.com/help/default.htm#parametric_methods/unpaired_t.htm) for formula reference.

```
x <- c(2,4,6,8,9,10,12,14)
y <- c(3,5,7,9,12,13,15,18)

tt <- function(x,y,mu0=0,ts=TRUE) { # two-sided t-test
  nx <- length(x)
  ny <- length(y)
  sp <- sqrt(((nx-1)*var(x)+(ny-1)*var(y))/(nx+ny-2))
  t <- (mean(x)-mean(y)-mu0) / (sp*sqrt(1/nx+1/ny))
  df <- (var(x)/nx + var(y)/ny)^2 / 
    ((var(x)/nx)^2/(nx-1) + (var(y)/ny)^2/(ny-1))

  sample_sizes <- c(nx, ny)
  names(sample_sizes) <- c("x","y")
  sample_means <- c(mean(x), mean(y))
  names(sample_means) <- c("x", "y")
  pvalue <- ifelse(ts,2,1)*(1-pt(abs(t),df=df))

  list(sample_sizes=sample_sizes, sample_means=sample_means,
       df=df, pvalue=pvalue)
}

tt(x,y)

# $sample_sizes
# x y 
# 8 8 
#
# $sample_means
#     x      y 
# 8.125 10.250 
#
# $df
# [1] 13.21697
#
# $pvalue
# [1] 0.3737564
```

**EDIT**

Here's how you can use this function for your example. Here's the first data set.

```
expr_data <- data.frame(matrix(
c("1007_s_at", "11.376519", "11.826743", "11.123022", "11.743439", "12.172961", 
"11.522009", "11.288407", "11.364544", "11.783231", "12.102697", "12.141934", 
"12.141672", "11.541161", "12.069206", "11.529456", "9.692066", "11.242988", 
"DDR1", "U48705", "1053_at", "7.270398", "7.534450", "7.169297", "7.730833", 
"6.728914", "7.033900", "8.152550", "7.357942", "7.811469", "6.704366",  
"7.723678", "7.607720", "6.904579", "6.837490", "7.437899", "7.608960", 
"6.704648", "RFC2", "M87338", "117_at", "8.172823", "8.350568", "8.216073", 
"8.052177", "7.940714", "8.122496", "8.246269", "7.597745", "8.809971", 
"7.299070", "7.808597", "8.390707", "7.653514", "8.680945", "8.050873", 
"9.242006", "8.253535", "HSPA6", "X51757", "121_at", "10.064195", 
"11.193688", "9.846189", "10.549992", "10.172722", "10.357284", "11.361081", 
"10.446139", "11.165541", "10.285435", "10.123556", "10.532735", 
"10.379335", "10.487541", "10.542419", "10.248043", "10.207259", "PAX8", 
"X69699", "1255_g_at", "6.256425", "6.830607", "5.825010", "6.098157", 
"6.104971", "5.818458", "6.355995", "6.311312", "7.366574", "5.577412", 
"4.570794", "5.046956", "6.561945", "5.897955", "5.402725", "5.957542", 
"6.201037", "GUCA1A", "L36861", "1294_at", "9.347887", "9.540260", 
"9.229501", "9.464348", "9.764903", "9.962180", "9.300450", "9.230649", 
"9.783263","8.749285", "9.466965", "9.653450", "9.076623", "9.827835", 
"9.096732", "9.441370", "9.102000", "UBA7", "L13852"), nrow=6, byrow=TRUE))

row.names(expr_data) <- expr_data[,1]
expr_data <- expr_data[,-1]
names(expr_data) <- c("GSM119944", "GSM119945", "GSM119946", "GSM119947", 
                      "GSM119948", "GSM119949", "GSM119950", "GSM119951", 
                      "GSM119952", "GSM119953", "GSM119954", "GSM119955", 
                      "GSM119956", "GSM119957", "GSM119958", "GSM119959", 
                      "GSM119960", "GeneSymbol", "PublicID")
expr_data[,1:17] <- sapply(expr_data[,1:17], function(x)
  as.numeric(as.character(x)))
```

And the second data set.

```
groups_data <- data.frame(
  PatientID=c('GSM119946','GSM119948','GSM119951','GSM119955','GSM119956',
              'GSM119959','GSM119947','GSM119950','GSM119952','GSM119953',
              'GSM119957','GSM119958','GSM119944','GSM119945','GSM119949',
              'GSM119954','GSM119960'),
  TreatmentGroup = c(rep('Control',6), rep('Treatment1',6), 
                     rep('Treatment2',5))
)
```

Then, perform the appropriate tests.

```
control_index <- which(groups_data$TreatmentGroup=="Control")
treatment_index <- which(groups_data$TreatmentGroup=="Treatment1")
# assume length(control_index) = length(treatment_index)
for(i in 1:length(control_index)) {
  control_group <- expr_data[,groups_data$PatientID[control_index[i]]]
  treatment_group <- expr_data[,groups_data$PatientID[treatment_index[i]]]
  cat("T-test for", as.character(groups_data$PatientID[control_index[i]]), "and", 
      as.character(groups_data$PatientID[treatment_index[i]]), "\n")
  result <- tt(control_group, treatment_group, 0, FALSE)
  cat("  sample sizes:", as.numeric(result$sample_sizes),"\n")
  cat("  sample means:", as.numeric(result$sample_means),"\n")
  cat("  degrees of freedom:", as.numeric(result$df),"\n")
  cat("  p-value:", as.numeric(result$pvalue),"\n\n")
}
```

**OUTPUT**

```
T-test for GSM119946 and GSM119947 
sample sizes: 6 6 
sample means: 8.568182 8.939824 
degrees of freedom: 9.947607 
p-value: 0.3759984 

T-test for GSM119948 and GSM119950 
sample sizes: 6 6 
sample means: 8.814198 9.117459 
degrees of freedom: 9.744115 
p-value: 0.4053794 

T-test for GSM119951 and GSM119952 
sample sizes: 6 6 
sample means: 8.718055 9.453342 
degrees of freedom: 9.916609 
p-value: 0.2560534 

T-test for GSM119955 and GSM119953 
sample sizes: 6 6 
sample means: 8.89554 8.453044 
degrees of freedom: 9.996676 
p-value: 0.38034 

T-test for GSM119956 and GSM119957 
sample sizes: 6 6 
sample means: 8.686193 8.966829 
degrees of freedom: 9.792449 
p-value: 0.4132705 

T-test for GSM119959 and GSM119958 
sample sizes: 6 6 
sample means: 8.698331 8.676684 
degrees of freedom: 9.134459 
p-value: 0.492472
```

**EDIT 2**

If you want to test the rows, you could use the following code.

```
control_cols <- groups_data$PatientID[which(groups_data$TreatmentGroup=="Control")]
treatment_cols <- groups_data$PatientID[which(groups_data$TreatmentGroup=="Treatment1")]

nrows <- dim(expr_data)[1]
for(i in 1:nrows) {
  control_group <- expr_data[i,control_cols]
  treatment_group <- expr_data[i,treatment_cols]

  cat("T-test for control vs treatment (", row.names(treatment_group), ")\n")
  result <- tt(as.numeric(control_group), as.numeric(treatment_group), 0, FALSE)
  cat("  sample sizes:", as.numeric(result$sample_sizes),"\n")
  cat("  sample means:", as.numeric(result$sample_means),"\n")
  cat("  degrees of freedom:", as.numeric(result$df),"\n")
  cat("  p-value:", as.numeric(result$pvalue),"\n\n")
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much Nathan, I have a microarray dataset and a corresponding control group dataset, that I need to use this function for, do you know how I could run a t-test for each gene in that dataset

Comment: Could you give a snapshot of the first few dataset rows in your original post?

Comment: I have edited my post, showing the dataset rows. Really appreciate your input

Comment: here you you :) @nathanesau

Comment: edited my answer. hopefully this answers your question.

Comment: Thank you :) I think I need to test the row and not the columns, dont know if thats possible. Also I need to test it against a null hypothesis that mu_control=mu_treat1 and an alternative hypothesis mu_control < mu_treat1. I need to compare the control group against treatment 1 group.

Comment: there are loads of rows, so I don't know if a loop needs created?

Comment: I could send you the actual datasets, if you want, that is only the head of a larger set.

Comment: Thank you so much, you have been a great help :)

Comment: I need to do this task now, alpha is a real number that satisfies 0 <= alpha <= 1. From these T test results, calculate the number of genes with p-value smaller than alpha. Show graphically how this
number changes as alpha changes from 0 to 1 with an increment step of 0.01. How do you generate graphs?

Comment: how can I determine which genes agree with alternative hypothesis and which agree with null. I really appreciate all your help :)

Comment: for the T-test how could I do this? hypothesized mean difference delta0,
and an option indicating left-tailed, right-tailed or two-tailed test

Comment: Also I need to calculate Effect size for each gene (row). so calculate the effect of Treatment1 with reference to Control and then calculate the effect of Treatment2 with reference to Control. For the effect size I know that I need the mean of each row for control minus the mean of each row for treatment1 /sd pooled. As for alpha first create a sequence of 0 to 1 that increases by 1.Then for each row on your genes get the p values of the treatment1 in to a vector.Now check your alpha value against your p values to see which p values fall low of alpha. Did that make any sense?

Comment: Please help, I'm sorry if I annoyed you Nathan

Comment: please help I have been trying for days to try and code this

Comment: Please help @nathanesau I have been staying up late every night to try and do this, still can't fully get it, can you even give me some advice

Comment: are you gonna help me or not? Could you even give me some advice to help me

Comment: Thank you so so much @nathanesau

Comment: Please can you tell me what code I use to calculate effect, look at my other question to see my data and reasoning. I am so so thankful for all you help and advice